# find total ram memory and swap memory

Tags: linux, scripting, memory

I need to write a script to find total memory and total swap of several linux server (2000+).
I have one trusted server from where I can login to all these 2000 servers without a password.

When I run this script, it should give output like this:

```
Server         total memory        swap
redhat1   
redhat2
redhat3
...
redhat2000
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

The `/proc/meminfo` file contains the information you're after. It's pretty easy to parse too.

This will get you the RAM and swap (in that order, unit is kB on all systems I know):

```
awk '/^(MemTotal|SwapTotal)/{print $2}' /proc/meminfo
```

To format it, you could do something like:

```
printf "%s\t%d\t%d\n" $(hostname) \
                      $(awk '/^(MemTotal|SwapTotal)/{print $2}' /proc/meminfo)
```

To combine that with ssh, do something like:

```
for host in your_list_of_servers ; do
  printf "%s\t%d\t%d\n" $host \
                   $(ssh $host "awk '/^(MemTotal|SwapTotal)/{print \$2}' /proc/meminfo")
done
```

Comment: this will help during logging to each server and execute it.

Comment: this would help if I am executing in each server
Here i have to do in 2000 server, it would be like logging to each server and execute command.


[root@master /]# ssh redhat1 'printf "%s\t%d\t%d\n" $(hostname)    $(awk '/^(MemTotal|SwapTotal)/{print $2}' /proc/meminfo)'
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Updated with an example of how you could do it in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

First You need to setup password less log-in, you can refer [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ssh-password-less-login-with-dsa-publickey-authentication/) page .

After that you can use below script as per your requirement.

```
#!/bin/bash
# store username:ip combo here separated by a whitespace
_pair="root@192.168.250.30 user1@192.168.x.x user1@192.x.x.x.x"

for e in $_pair
do
        # extract user and ips for each $e in $_pair
        IFS='@'
        set -- $e
        _user="$1"
        _ip="$2"

        sleep 2
        echo "Connecting to server '${_ip}' via SSH..."
        ssh ${_user}@${_ip} "free -m | awk -v h=$HOSTNAME '(/Mem/||/Swap/){printf("%s\t%s%d\t",h,$1,$2)}'; echo -e"
done
```

Comment: output is in this way
redhat1 Mem: 7855M
redhat1 Swap: 3371M



can you tell me how to get in this way
redhat1  7855M  3371M

Comment: output is in this way
redhat1 Mem: 7855M
redhat1 Swap: 3371M



can you tell me how to get in this way
redhat1  7855M  3371M

Comment: @ashwini I have Updated as per your requirement Please check it now.